# I used *pointer+1 in my printf function and it didn't turn out what i thought it would be . why?

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the C code i recently ran and i got result that i didn't expect

Now the result i expected was **"o"** but what i got in the result was **H** and i want to know why?

**My thoughts and what i knew :-**

What i knew is that in a pointer the data stored is a number which points to the place we tends to point ..

for example:- if we declare a as 
`char *pointer`then The C will make some memory for pointer 
and if we do  `pointer = "GOKU"`the C will make a separate memory of 5 bits for this string somewhere in the memory cells. Now let the memory cell in which `G`is stored to be `50` so in the **pointer ** which let's say is stored in memory cell 100 will have the value `50`. So now this pointer which is at poistion of `100`th memory cell has a value of `50` which is pointing towards the 'G' character of GOKU..

And i thought if i increase the pointer by 1 then it will jump to memory location 51 where O will be stored but turns out that is not true . It turns out that when i increase the pointer by 1 something happens and it responds to H which falls right next to G in alphabetical order as well as in ASCII table . I ran several test but couldn't get `E` as output from the program . I knew i can use indexing as to get but i still want to know why this happened.

thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
char *pointer = "GOKU";

printf(" %c ", *pointer+1);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `*pointer` is `'G'` and `'G' + 1` is `'H'`. Did you want `*(pointer + 1)`?

Comment: ASCII value of `G` is  `71` adding 1 to it gives `72` which is an ASCII value of `H`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer dereference operator `*` has higher precedence than the addition operator `+`.  So this:

```
*pointer+1
```

Is the same as:

```
(*pointer)+1
```

What you're doing is dereferencing `pointer` *first*, giving you the character `'G'`.  You then add 1 to that value to give you `'H'`.

If you want to add to the pointer, you need to add parenetheses:

```
*(pointer+1)
```

This will increment the pointer by 1, *then* dereference the pointer to give you `'O'`.

The above, by the way, is the same as:

```
pointer[1]
```

Comment: Thanks dbush , your answer cleared a lot of doubts that i have. Also i wanna mention that  it is so amazing that a really basic thing can do so much . Computer programming is amazing

Comment: @JayantShivam Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.